# Extraer palabra de una cadena a partir de un simbolo

Tags: php, string

Necesito buscar en una cadena, os pongo un ejemplo:

"Texto de prueba #palabra blablablabla"

Necesitaria extraer "#pablabra". He visto que con "strpos($string, "#")" puedo sacar la posición donde esta el #, pero como puedo a partir de esa posición extraer la palabra que acabaría en un espacio. Esa palabra puede ser cualquier cosa, un nombre, un objeto etc, por eso digo que la palabra acabaria cuando haya un espacio :)

Siento si me explico mal, muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

Lo ideal en este caso es usar expresiones regulares. En tu caso, quieres algo que empiece por `#` y contenga todas las letras hasta el próximo espacio, coma, punto, etc. Algo como `/(\#[\wáéíóúüñ]+)/` (`\w` representa todos los caracteres que pueden componer una palabra, pero no conoce las tildes, por eso están añadidas aparte).

Luego lo aplicas via preg_match() y tendrás todos los patrones encontrados.

```
<?php
$cadena = "Texto de prueba #palabra blablablabla";

preg_match('/(\#[\wáéíóúüñ]+)/g', $cadena, $patrones); // mete todo lo encontrado en el array $patrones

print_r($patrones); // Muestra los resultados
```

?>